Configuring SSRS to Use Conditional Linked Server Connections Based on User Data
Let me explain my situation:
Server A: This is my SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) server, which hosts all users and source connections.
SQL Server B: This server is used for query connections created in the SSRS Server. Server B has two linked server connections with Impala: one for unmasked data and one for masked data, each using a different user account created on the Hadoop side. These masking implementations are managed in Apache Atlas/Ranger.
I want to configure SSRS on Server A such that user data determines which linked server connection (masked or unmasked) is used when running queries on Server B.
Could you provide any configuration guidance for this setup?

If you want masked data, why are you not using one server with Dynamic Data Masking? Then you could ensure that users who should be connecting to "Server B", instead don't have permission to UNMASK the data in Server A; then you don't even need a server B. This sounds like an XY Problem to me,

Also, how is [[tag:impala]] related to the question?

This is kinda tricky, but perhaps if you have a view which does create View x AS select userid, * from maskedusers u cross join openquery(maskedserver, '...') oq union all select userid, * from unmaskedusers u cross join openquery(unmaskedserver, '...') oq and then select from the view based on userID

I have over 400 reports which Called through Hadoop, developed by different developers, all of which currently use a single linked server. Now, my situation has changed and I need to implement grouping on the SQL Server side. However, the reports always call the previous linked server instead of the new two linked servers (one for masked data and one for unmasked data).

Maybe this answer is what you're after? Dynamically set the data source for SSRS reports

Also How to use Dynamic data sources in your SSRS report..

No, This will take lot of time and effort to update all reports, Also my condition is restriction on SSRS Users.
